# @devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4 throuwing a peer dependency warning

Tags: devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-react

When installing the package @devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4, it's throwing a warning about the peer dependencies caused by its depency package react-popper.

@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4 version: 4.0.5
react-popper version: 2.2.5

This issue is resolved in the version 2.3.0 of react-popper.

I tried to submit a pull request in the [devextreme-reactive](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive) repository but I wasn't able to (the PRs are limited to contributors).

I'm opening this issue in the hope that a contributor of that devextreme-reactive sees this and opens it themselves.